# HTTPServletRequest getServerPort returning -1

Tags: java, servlets

Today I found the little surprise that getServerPort() can return a -1. I use the port to build the hostname like this:

```
String hostName = request.getServerName().toString();
Integer urlPort = request.getServerPort();

if((urlPort != null) && (urlPort.intValue() != 80) && (urlPort.intValue() != 443) && (urlPort.intValue() != -1)) {
    hostName += ":" + urlPort;
}
```

- Why is returning a -1? I expected it would always be 80/443
- Is there a prettier way to build the hostname?

Comment: When getServerPort() returns a `-1` that means that the server port was undefined.

Comment: You shouldn't need to build the hostname at all, just a relative URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerPort()

It will return -1 if the port was not specified in the URL. 
Typically in a browser, it is common to access http without the port, which the browser will default to 80.
Likewise, https defaults to 443;

You can't depend or expect the port to be specified in all cases and should code to check that. You are checking for port == -1, checking for null is unnecessary as the method returns a primitive int and will never be null.

If you want to detect http or https, then use the 
getScheme() method no the request: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getScheme

Comment: then use the `getScheme()` method ***on*** the request, not no.